# How to fix Pandas extract data?

Tags: python, pandas

I use this rule in pandas to find value in dataframe in specific column then return some columns back. If it is fails. I got the error.

```
unpack = dfzips.loc[dfzips.zip == element, ['city', 'county_name', 'state_name', "state_id"]].values[0]
```

Error is:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

How to fit it?

Comment: `dfzips.zip == element` selects empty row.

Comment: I did not get you

Comment: What is zip? Are you trying to use the zip() function or do you have a column called "zip"?

Comment: zip it is name of column from dataframe

Comment: I try  to find value in frame and return other columns values if found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to check if there is at least on row having element `value` in  `zip` column or not. If there is at least one row that `zip` columns contains `element` value, then run your code, else do nothing (e.g. use `continue` command if you are doing in the loop).

For example,

```py
unpack = []
for element in list_of_element:
    if (dfzips.zip == element).sum() > 0:
        unpack += [dfzips.loc[dfzips.zip == element, ['city', 'county_name', 'state_name', "state_id"]].values[0]]
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: You need to append each value to `unpack`. The way it is, `unpack` will hold only the value of the last iteration.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for your comment, I just want to show the use of `if` and `continue` statement. However, I edited my answer according to your suggestion :)